# Change all four margins by a certain amount, temporarily, in book documentclass

Tags: geometry, books, documentclass

Is there a way to *subtract* a certain amount of space from all four margins (top, bottom, left, and right) in a document that has (say) `\documentclass[11pt]{book}`? I wish to temporarily (for a couple pages) subtract a little space from all four margins, then go back to normal afterward.

Comment: By use of the `geometry` package command `newgeometry` or `changepage` and use `\changetext{<text height>}{<text width>}{<even-side margin>}
{<odd-side margin>}{<column sep>}`.

Comment: Please tell us how you're setting the margins at present. Do you employ the `geometry` package?

Comment: Are these consecutive pages, or is it one here, one elsewhere?

Comment: @Werner They are two consecutive pages.

Comment: @Mico Sorry I forgot to mention that! I am using `\usepackage[paperwidth=4.25in, paperheight=5.5in]{geometry}` after `\documentclass[11pt]{book}`.